# URL Rewriting - Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I work on an MVC application and I have urls in the following format:

```
http://127.0.0.1/PDO/PARTIE%20III/index.php?rt=index/connexion
http://127.0.0.1/PDO/PARTIE%20III/index.php?rt=index/nouveauMsg
```

I am seeking to rewrite the url so that it reads:

```
http://127.0.0.1/PDO/PARTIE%20III/index/connexion
http://127.0.0.1/PDO/PARTIE%20III/index/nouveauMsg
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to help me complete this url_rewrite?

That's the router Class that parses the URL and loads the correct view and/or action

```
<?php

class router {
 /*
 * @the registry
 */
 private $registry;

 /*
 * @the controller path
 */
 private $path;

 private $args = array();

 public $file;

 public $controller;

 public $action; 

 function __construct($registry) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
 }

 /**
 *
 * @set controller directory path
 *
 * @param string $path
 *
 * @return void
 *
 */
 function setPath($path) {

/*** check if path i sa directory ***/
if (is_dir($path) == false)
{
    throw new Exception ('Invalid controller path: `' . $path . '`');
}
/*** set the path ***/
$this->path = $path;
}


 /**
 *
 * @load the controller
 *
 * @access public
 *
 * @return void
 *
 */
 public function loader()
 {
/*** check the route ***/
$this->getController();

/*** if the file is not there diaf ***/
if (is_readable($this->file) == false)
{
    $this->file = $this->path.'/error404.php';
            $this->controller = 'error404';
}

/*** include the controller ***/
include $this->file;

/*** a new controller class instance ***/
$class = $this->controller . 'Controller';
$controller = new $class($this->registry);

/*** check if the action is callable ***/
if (is_callable(array($controller, $this->action)) == false)
{
    $action = 'index';
}
else
{
    $action = $this->action;
}
/*** run the action ***/
$controller->$action();
 }


 /**
 *
 * @get the controller
 *
 * @access private
 *
 * @return void
 *
*/
private function getController() {

/*** get the route from the url ***/
$route = (empty($_GET['rt'])) ? '' : $_GET['rt'];

if (empty($route))
{
    $route = 'index';
}
else
{
    /*** get the parts of the route ***/
    $parts = explode('/', $route);
    $this->controller = $parts[0];
    if(isset( $parts[1]))
    {
        $this->action = $parts[1];
    }
}

if (empty($this->controller))
{
    $this->controller = 'index';
}

/*** Get action ***/
if (empty($this->action))
{
    $this->action = 'index';
}

/*** set the file path ***/
$this->file = $this->path .'/'. $this->controller . 'Controller.php';
}


}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Use this rewrite rule in a `.htaccess` in your document root or Apache config file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^PDO/PARTIE%20III/(.*)$ PDO/PARTIE%20III/index.php?rt=$1 [L]
```

You can test rewrite rules easily at [Martin Melin's site](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).

For more information: [Apache's `mod_rewrite` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i appreciate that. But, I've tested this rule and it's not working.
Do i miss something?

Comment: I've updated the question — please let me know if this one works. The `.htaccess` should be put in your site root.

Comment: Stil not working :S ... u can download the sample here http://www.phpro.org/downloads/mvc-0.0.4.tar.gz